# Collapse bootstrap 4 não funciona mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Estou com problema em um collapse com bootstrap 4 no modo mobile.

Ele abre normalmente mas não fecha, eu já gastei um bom tempo tentando resolver e mais ainda pesquisando! Por favor me ajudem...

**Por favor verifiquem na resolução correta como da imagem.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link: https://codepen.io/lucas-granvilla-da-silva/pen/aQPPJB

Comment: Amigo edite sua pergunta com o código, só a imagem não ajuda muito. E vc tb esqueceu de colocar o link... Outra coisa que reparei, cado o Btn que tem que clicar para abrir o menu??

Comment: :O o esqueci de colar o código, perdão!

Comment: O botão para abrir é o título

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é simples, seu `btn` de "menu" está com position:absolute, assim ele fica "encoberto" pelo conteúdo de se abre quando clica.

Basta adicionar um `z-index` nesse `btn` do menu que vc resolve o problema

Veja:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans');

* {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}


#categorias .categoria {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0 10%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

#categorias h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#categorias .layout-1 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#categorias .layout-2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#categorias .layout-3 a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-sub {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: 0px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-sub ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.menu-sub ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 1px;
  background: #4775b8;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.menu-sub ul li:hover {
  background: #2e3b84;
}

.menu-sub ul li.ativa {
  background: #2e3b84;
  border: 25px solid #fff;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.menu-sub ul li.ativa a {
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
}

.menu-sub ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-sub ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cart-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-height: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {

  .list-produtos {
    margin-top: 30px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .list-menu {
    margin-top: 45px;
  }

  .menu-desktop {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-sub {
    max-width: none;
  }

  .menu-sub ul li.ativa {
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: auto;
  }

  .menu-sub ul li.ativa a {
    position: static;
  }

  .max-100 {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
.menubar-mobile {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



 <div class="col-12 menubar-mobile position-absolute" id="menulist-mobile">
  <h2 class="text-center" id="menulist-mobile" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-sub"
   aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="#menu-sub">Categorias</h2>
 </div>


 <div id="menu-sub" class="col-md-2 menu-sub altura2 collapse" style="">
  <ul class="list-menu">
   <li class="ativa"><a href="produtos/3-acessorios-para-esquadrias/59-adega?p=1">Adega</a></li>
   <li><a href="produtos/3-acessorios-para-esquadrias/60-bandeja?p=1">Bandeja</a></li>
   <li><a href="produtos/3-acessorios-para-esquadrias/61-banquetas?p=1">Banquetas</a></li>
   <li><a href="produtos/3-acessorios-para-esquadrias/62-cabides?p=1">Cabides</a></li>
   <li><a href="produtos/3-acessorios-para-esquadrias/63-calceiros?p=1">Calceiros</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: amo esse site!

como posso não ter percebido algo tão simples.

Comment: @Lucas vou te dar uma dica valiosa, que vc pode usar tanto no Chrome como FireFox. Sempre que tiver esse tipo de problema, vai no DevTools do browser. Ou clica com o botão direito do mouse no elemento com problema e manda "Inspecionar" ai vc vai habilitando e desabilitando os CSS em tempo real, e vai mexendo até encontrar o problema. A DevTools é poderosa e deve ser usada! Tem até tutorial ensinando a trabalhar com ela, vale uma pesquisa da sua arte. Boa sorte ai

Comment: Eu uso ela, mas fiz vários testes, comparei com a documentação no bootstrap, achei que fosse algo do servidor aí testei no codepen e vi que era no código. Testei somente com o css necessário para ver se era alguma outra propriedade, porém nem assim. Por isso disse que não sei como não testei isto. Ainda bem que tenho vocês. Tenho de começar a usar mais este site, uso muito pouco.

Comment: @Lucas tem muita gente fera aqui, profissional de alto nível mesmo e que está disposta a ajudar. Use sempre que precisar sem moderação rss, só tenha cuidado para fazer sempre perguntas completas e objetivas. []´s

Answer (score 2):

Sem entrar no mérito do código, o problema é que no modo mobile a div do menu está ficando por cima do texto que o controla.

Adicione `z-index: 1` na `div#menulist-mobile` dentro do @media:

```
#menulist-mobile{
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Isso fará com que a div que abriga o `<h2>` fique por cima da div do menu.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta amigo! o rapaz ali respondeu antes por isso dei pra ele a resposta!

Comment: Falô colega! Boa sorte!